# shp2pgsql creates a table but psql reports "relation...does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Using shp2pgsql to import a shapefile into a PostGIS database, all works fine:

```
Connection: host=localhost port=5432 user=aperrin dbname=tweets password='******' 
Destination: public.County_2010Census_DP1
Source File: /home/aperrin/Downloads/County_2010Census_DP1/County_2010Census_DP1
Shapefile type: Polygon
Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
Importing shapefile (3221 records)...
Creating spatial index...

Shapefile import completed.
```

In psql, \d shows:

```
                          List of relations
 Schema |                  Name                   |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+-----------------------------------------+----------+----------
 public | County_2010Census_DP1                   | table    | aperrin
 public | County_2010Census_DP1_gid_seq           | sequence | aperrin
```

However:

```
tweets=> \d County_2010Census_DP1
Did not find any relation named "County_2010Census_DP1".
tweets=> select * from County_2010Census_DP1;
ERROR:  relation "county_2010census_dp1" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from County_2010Census_DP1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an all-lower-case table name fixed the problem. Used us_counties as the table name.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes when using capital table names.

```
   select * from "County_2010Census_DP1";
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need add postgis extension to database using this code:

```
psql -U username -d databasename
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```